# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty } n\cdot a_n\cdot a_{n+1}$ where $a_n =\int_0^{\pi/2}((\sin x)^n) dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

The question is to evaluate the limit
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty } n\cdot a_n\cdot a_{n+1}$$
where
$$a_n =\int_0^{\pi/2}((\sin x)^n) dx$$

I just evaluated the limits for natural numbers $n$ and got $\frac{\pi}2$. Is it correct to do this?

To find $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty } f(x)$, is it enough to to evaluate the limit for $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}?$ And are there any other ways to solve this question?

Comment: The limit is indeed $\pi/2$. Check https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4393369/72031 And please typeset the math using mathjax (see [tutorial designed for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site)).

Comment: Thank you , you can close this question.